# discord py сообщение с левой рамкой

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Как отправлять через модуль discord в python сообщения, с левой боковой рамкой, и как поменять её цвет?

картинка для примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: почитай про [`discord.Embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта рамка называется "**Эмбед**", её достаточно легко сделать. Вот код дальше сам разберешься.

```
@bot.command() 
async def testembed(ctx): 
    embed=discord.Embed(
     title="Заголовок", #заголовок эмбеда
     url="", #ссылка в заголовке
     description="Описание", #описание
     color=0xe100ff) #цвет эмбета
    embed.set_author(
        name = ctx.author.display_name, #'ctx.author.display_name' - имя вызывающего. ' "Автор" ' -  любой автор
        icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url) #иконка автора
    embed.set_thumbnail(
        url="") #миниатюра, а точнее вставка фото
    embed.add_field(
        name="Поле1", #название поля
        value="Описание", #описание поля
        inline=False)
    embed.add_field(
        name="Поле1", 
        value="Описание", 
        inline=True)
    embed.add_field(
        name="Поле2", 
        value="Описание", 
        inline=True)  
    embed.set_image(
        url='')
    embed.set_footer(
        text="Подвал", #Текст в низу *подвал
        icon_url='') #ctx.autor.avatar_url 
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def embed(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        embed=discord.Embed(
            description='This is embed!'
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command()
async def (название команды)(ctx):
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(description = f"Привет мир!", color = discord.Color.purple()))
```

вместо цвета purple можно добавить:
[image: вот эти цвета:]

Answer (score 0):

называется Embed. Есть везде, и в JS и в Python. Вот тебе образец для питона:

```py
embed = discord.Embed( # Корень эмбеда
    title = "Название", # Название эмбеда
    description = "Описание", # Описание эмбеда (до 4К символов)
    timestamp = ..., # Таймстамп (временная метка)
    color = 0xFFFFFF, # Цвет левого бордера (после 0x ставишь HEX-цвет)
)
embed.set_author( # Автор
    name = "Имя", # Текст автора
    icon_url = "https://" # Ссылка на иконку
)
embed.set_thumbnail( # Картинка-миниатюра
    url = "https://" # Ссылка на картинку-миниатюру
)
embed.set_image( # Полноразмерная картинка
    url = "https://" # Ссылка на полноразмерную картинку
)
embed.add_field( # Поле
    name = "Название", # Название поля
    value = "Значение" # Значение поля
)
embed.set_footer( # Футер
    text = "Это подвал",
    icon_url = "https://" # Ссылка на картинку для футера
)
```

думаю как отправить спрашивать не надо :)
остальное есть в доках d.py, и в других по типу dislash, disnake и т.д.